# Random fade-in and fade-out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, testing

I need each of the sparkles below to fade in and fade out randomly, not all at once though. 1-2 at a time is ok. Also, I do not want the "Pack" image to fade. I do not want the sparkles to fade in/out due to a function like on hover. I also need them all of them to disappear after 5 seconds. Please help, I have tried everything, can't figure it out.. I'm new to web development and javascript.

Here is a fiddle I found, I would like it to be similar to this, I tried editing the code. I'm very confused right now.

http:// jsfiddle(dot)net/maniator/rcts4/ - Fiddle (I couldn't upload more than 2 links, please take out the space after http:// and replace the "(dot)" with . to view the Fiddle.

http://pastebin.com/DkDjU0qS - HTML
http://pastebin.com/Zr1vjafn - CSS

Comment: please set up a http://plnkr.co/ (or http://jsfiddle.net/) page with your code

Comment: Alright, I have added it to plnkr.co - http://plnkr.co/edit/pGc2YcI06ES0eCjTB575?p=preview

Comment: but there is no JS code ...

Comment: Oops, sorry. Forgot to add what I tried. That was my old version. I have updated it. http://plnkr.co/edit/pGc2YcI06ES0eCjTB575?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Pack -->
        <img id="pack" src="http://cloud.attackofthefanboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/fifa14pack.png">

        <!-- Sparkles-->
    <div id="sparkles">

        <img id="sparkle1" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle2" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle3" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle4" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle5" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle6" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle7" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">

        <img id="sparkle8" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/L/F/v/7/8/sparkle-md.png">
        </div>
        <script>

        // Define a random integer function
        function random(n) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
        }

        // Define some variables, hide all images and show just one of them.
        var transition_time = 500;
        var waiting_time = 500;
        var images = $('div#sparkles img');
        var n = images.length;
        var current = random(n);

        images.hide();
        images.eq(current).show();

        // Periodically, we fadeOut the current image and fadeIn a random one
        var interval_id = setInterval(function () {
             images.eq(current).fadeOut(transition_time, function () {
                 current = random(n);
                 images.eq(current).fadeIn(transition_time);
             });
        }, 2 * transition_time + waiting_time);

       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
 html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        background-color: white;
    }

    #pack {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 300px;
        width: 200px;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -100px;
    }

    #sparkle1 {
        position: absolute;
        top: -8%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 140px;
        width: 150px;
    }

    #sparkle2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 90%;
        left: 57%;
        height: 180px;
        width: 155px;
    }

    #sparkle3 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 94%;
        left: 29%;
        height: 140px;
        width: 115px;
    }

    #sparkle4 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        left: 86%;
        height: 150px;
        width: 123px;
    }

    #sparkle5 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 83%;
        height: 145px;
        width: 118px;
    }

    #sparkle6 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 79%;
        right: 82%;
        height: 150px;
        width: 120px;
    }

    #sparkle7 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 52%;
        right: 85%;
        height: 150px;
        width: 130px;
    }

    #sparkle8 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 85%;
        height: 180px;
        width: 160px;
    }

    #sparkles {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;

        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        margin-top: -250px;
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/UxLhE/2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This definitely helped, but I'm not too familiar with Javascript.. :/ I'm not sure how transition times, etc. work. I tried fooling around with this code as well on Plunker but I wasn't able to make it function.

Comment: This is Milliseconds, I will update the JSFiddle with your code.

Comment: Thank you SO much for this, it's working perfectly! :) Is there any way to stop the same sparkle of repeating? I noticed it has been happening a lot.

Comment: Just comment or remove this line like this: //images.eq(current).show(); Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/felipekm/UxLhE/3/ -- attempt to the 14 line of the JavaScript window.